# RSA public key and resulting ciphertext

Tags: number-theory

I was asked to solve the question below

An RSA public key is given by $n = 2183, C = 895$. Find the decoding key D; this RSA public key was used to encrypt a number x in the range $1 ≤ x ≤ 999$. The resulting ciphertext is $y = 821$. Find the value of x.

For the first bit, i got the following calculation. Since $46^2 < 2183 < 47^2$. $47^2 = 2209,$, $2209 - 2183 = 26$ which is not a square number , $48^2 = 2304$
 and , $2304- 2183= 121 = 11^2$. Then $2183 = 48^2 - 11^2$ = $59$    x $37$. Since $59$ and $37$ are prime,  $φ(n) = 58$ x $36 = 2088$. The Euclidean algorthim gives $2088 = 2$ x $895 + 298$, $895 = 3$ x $298 + 1$. Then substitution gives
 $1 = 895 - 3 $x $( 2088 - 2 $x $895 ) = 7$ x $895 - 3$ x $2088 = 1$. Thus

$7$ x $895 ≡ 1$ mod  $φ(2088)$. So the decoding key is $D = 7$.

And then i was so confused and i get stuck with the second bit of the question which is to find the value of x with a resulting ciphertext $y = 821$.

Can anyone give me some hints?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If $x$ is encoded and the encoding key is $C$, the result is $y\equiv x^C\bmod n$. Then, if $CD\equiv 1\bmod \phi(n),$

$$x\equiv x^{CD}\equiv y^D\bmod n.$$

Does that help?